# Tire Elastic search: Deleting a record from model and redirecting immediately throws error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tire

I am having a model named `User`. When I destroy a user and redirect to the User's index page, it throws an exception
`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find all Users with IDs (1, 200) (found 1 results, but was looking for 2)` 
But when I refresh the page, the page loads properly and displays all the users. The problem I guess is `Tire::Model::Callbacks after_destroy` is taking some time to execute and if I call `User.search_all` within that time period the result is searched including the destroyed id.
I am looking for a clean approach to overcome this problem. Or does Tire have any option to handle this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

send a refresh call to Elasticsearch before you invoke User.search_all. Elasticsearch refresh_interval defaults to 1 second, so if you delete from it and do a search under a second, it might not have a chance to remove the deleted record before return results to you.